# Is there a way to change bytes to ints while reading from an input stream in Java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, performance

I'm reading in a file with an InputStream to a byte array, and then changing each byte into an int. Then I store the int into another array. Is there a way to make this more efficient? Specifically, is there a way to use only one array instead of two? Allocating both of the arrays is taking too long for my program.

This is what I am doing right now (`is` is the InputStream):

```
byte[] a = new byte[num];
int[] b = new int[num];

try {
    is.read(a, 0, num);
    for (int j = 0; j < nPixels; j++) {
        b[j] = (int) a[j] & 0xFF; //converting from a byte to an "unsigned" int
    }
} catch (IOException e) { }
```

Comment: I hope you are aware that read(byte[] b, int off, int len) is not guaranteed to read the full buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets see... you can't read int's directly since that will try to read 4 bytes at a time. You could say

```
int_array[j] = (int)is.read();
```

inside the loop if you're ok with reading the stream one byte at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It turns out that the run time is longer than what I had before though, so I'll have to look for another way to code it efficiently I guess.

Comment: in the abstract base class InputStream, read(byte[]) is defined in terms of the abstract method read(). However, subclasses can override read(byte[]) to make it more efficient then simply using a bunch of reads. Using two arrays shouldn't occupy enough memory to be problematic, unless you have HUGE arrays... another solution would be to try to use the byte array as is. Too bad java doesn't have unions.

Comment: Unfortunately I do have pretty big arrays (it's for decoding an image file). It's an even bigger problem for android platforms! D:

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into [DataInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) or even [FileInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)? There are many more methods that allow you to read specific data types right from an InputStream.

I don't know if this is possible in your situation with only the information you provided.

Comment: In my case, i'm converting each byte in the stream to an int, and I'm afraid that something like the DataInputStream will put 4 bytes into an int, which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the no-argument method InputStream.read() which returns an int?

```
File file = new File("/tmp/test");
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
int fileSize = (int) file.length(); // ok for files < Integer.MAX_SIZE bytes
int[] fileBytesAsInts = new int[fileSize];
for(int j = 0; j < fileSize; j++) {
    fileBytesAsInts[j] = fis.read();
}
```